# Using multiprocessing.Pool() for rather large iterators seems not to start

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to do some evaluation on a very large iterator.

Just as an example, I want to select a subset of 30 elements from a total of 70 elements and calculate some cost for each selection. To decide which selection is the best, the target ist to minimize the calculated cost. On a single CPU, this will run for multiple weeks, or even forever.

Now the idea is to use the multiprocessing module to speed it up by a factor of 8 ... 24, depending on the available logical cores. Even though, that a speedup of 24 is not overwhelming, I would be happy to get any thoughts about the processing problems I see. Any ideas would be really appreciated.

In total there are in this example 70!/(30!*(70-30)!) possible selections, which is something around 5.5e19.
Even if calculating a cost would just take only 1 ms, overall runtime would be anyhow rather long.
Independently how long it would take to calculate the cost for a single selection, multiprocessing does not start as expected.

When reducing the size of the iterable by factors (e.g. selecting 3 elements out of 70, results in a total of just 54740 possbile selections) processing starts as expected.

I tried to use multiprocessing.Pool (the following code is just an example to show the principle):

```
list_of_elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
# the data pool is a list of 4 element combinations selected out of the list of elements
data_pool = list(map(" ".join, itertools.combinations(list_of_elements, 4)))
# so the first element of data pool would be most likely 'a b c d' and with selecting 4 out of 8
# without repetition, there are 70 potential selections)
size_of_data_pool = len(data_pool) # = 70
sel_size = 30  # or selSize = 3

# total number of combinations to be evaluated
total_nr_of_combinations = math.factorial(size_of_data_pool) / (math.factorial(sel_size ) * math.factorial(size_of_data_pool - sel_size))  # ~5.5e19

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(calc_cost, itertools.combinations(combs, sel_size))
```

It looks like, that the pool.map mechanism evaluates the complete space of input data before really
starting the processing, since it takes forever and I don't see any start info from the calc_cost function.
With selSize = 3 this info shows up rather immediately.

What is the best way to handle such large iterator sizes. When starting these investigations, I first used
lists incuding the data_pool info. To prevent from first building up the complete input data_pool, I thought
iterators/generators are the solution. In my case itertools.combinations does the job very well, but the
overall size of data elements to be processed is so large, that processing get's nasty.

Searching the web did not allow me to understand the issue here. I had the hope, that the cost falls below a certain threshold already after evaluating only a poriton of the total space of overall selections.
So any idea on how to handly such problems and/or an explanation/idea, why multiprocssing does not start as expected, would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but did you finish doing the math?  5.5e19 items, at 1ms per item, takes 6e11 days.  If you use a 24 core CPU you reduce this to 3e10 days, an insignificant improvement.  Homo sapiens appeared on the planet only about 3e8 days ago (~100,000 years).  The best way to handle such large iterator sizes is to avoid them.  It seems to me you need a new approach to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
That's why I already stated, that 24 is not overwhelming. So the question is not if that is possible to be finished, but more why the concept of interables/generators does not work here. To start paralell processing, there should be also no need to know the total input space. If 24 processing chains are available, it takes the first 24 chunks of the iterator and start processing. Even though it might never end. The plain for loop does exactly this and is not worrying about the immense iteration count.
I thought that iterators are especially contructed to handle this.